# Sort nested array alphabetically by value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

How can I sort alphabetically this multidimensional-array, by the value of the "code" key?

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Products] => Array
            (
                [code] => LD
                [power] => 5
                [channels] => 2
            )
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [Products] => Array
            (
                [code] => CAE
                [power] => 15
                [channels] => 1
            )
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [Products] => Array
            (
                [code] => FC
                [power] => 12
                [channels] => 1
            )
    )
```

I have checked other post, but no one has an array like this.

EDIT: this is my attempt

```
function sortByCode($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a['code'], $b['code']);
}
```

and then:

```
usort($myarray['Products'], 'sortByCode');
```

I know it's wrong, but I don't know how make it work!

Comment: Have you tried anything? Like usort() maybe?

Comment: Yes, I've already used usort() as explained in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value  ...without success

Comment: @Andrea Then add your attempt and show us where you are stuck

Comment: @Andrea You were close. You forgot the dimension: `Products`, just use it like this: `usort($arr, function($a, $b){
   return strcasecmp($b["Products"]["code"], $a["Products"]["code"]);
  });`

Comment: @Rizier123 ty for your help, but doesn't work..'usort() [function.usort]: Invalid comparison function'

Comment: @Andrea Then you don't show us your real code/array

Comment: @Andrea See it working: http://3v4l.org/eHmeK

Comment: @Rizier123 It may depend on the my version 5.2.6 of php?

Comment: @Andrea Ah yeah, then it's just a version problem: http://3v4l.org/ailmf

Comment: @Rizier123 I've solved with: usort($arr, array($this, "mySort")); even if I don't know why! xD very thanks :))

Comment: @Andrea Nice that you have solved it. ^ I see your code is in a class.